# How to compare the items in array and replace,And also set the index at particular index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is running code into the html and simple JavaScript to display items into the select element.
Currently the select items are coming from the **options** array,There are also one array named **days**

Here I want to compare the array **options** with the **days** and whatever the item index into the days similar I want into the options array .
So,After comparing the array my options array would be similar to days array.
so the drop down should display items in sequence like 'day','week','month','yearly','sixmonth' and this should come from the options array

```js
var options = ["day", "yearly","week", "sixmonth",'month'];

var days = ['day','week','month','yearly','sixmonth']
var s = document.getElementById("selectCity");
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  s.innerHTML += `<option value=${i}> ${options[i]}</option>`;
}
```

```html
 <select id="selectCity">
        <option>Choose a City</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what you're looking for. You want options and days to be... the same? ordered the same? You're declaring them right next to each other in this example, so there's no reason you can't just only use the one array. What are each one for? Could you please clarify a little better? Thanks. Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way :)

Comment: You want options and days to be... the same? yes .The options is coming from dynamically and days are static
But the order of item index is different in options array and I want similar to days array

Comment: As the question was not clear. I am assuming that the options array is a subset of days array and days array should be used as a reference for filtering and sorting the options array. If that's the case we can just filter the days array by the checking the values index in the options array and the resultant array will become your result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming days is a subset of options and you want all options array values to be sorted as per the indexing of items in days. And any extra item in options array will be coming at last as per their order of occurrence.

Here is the code

```
      var options = ["day", "yearly","week", "sixmonth",'month',"newMonth"];
      var days = ['day','week','month','yearly','sixmonth']
      var sorted=days.filter(val=>options.includes(val))
      options = options.filter(val => !days.includes(val))
      sorted.push(...options)
      console.log(sorted)
      var s = document.getElementById("selectCity");
      for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
           s.innerHTML += `<option value=${i}> ${sorted[i]}</option>`;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I take it to mean that options is a subset of days and that you want options to be sorted such that it has the same order as days.

Here is an example:

```
var options = ["day", "yearly","week", "sixmonth",'month'];

var days = ['day','week','month','yearly','sixmonth'];

var sortedOptions = options.sort((a, b) => days.indexOf(a) - days.indexOf(b))

var s = document.getElementById("selectCity");
for (var i = 0; i < sortedOptions.length; i++) {
    s.innerHTML += `<option value=${i}> ${sortedOptions[i]}</option>`;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stanley

But options contains dynamic values like
options = ["day", "yearly","week", "sixmonth",'month' ,"TenMonth" ,"ThreeMonth"];

In this case also it would be ordered as per the days and it contains items which is equal into the both array.

In this case it would be display
['day','week','month','yearly','sixmonth'];

Comment: the above solution only works if whatever value that is dynamically generated in options is also included in the days array ... so you would need to include them into days array